# Data Lineage tools for AWS data engineering?

Tags: database, data-analysis, cloud-service

My project uses AWS resources for data engineering. We use tools such as s3 for source, glue for transform and RDS as warehouse and several other. What are some of the best recommended and mostly used tools that can help with data lineage documentation.